# Creating procedure doesnt work, Gives me no error code

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with getting the code below to work, when i input it into mysql it doesn't give me a specific error it only says error with no reason or any error number, anyone who can help me notice if there is something i'm forgetting or doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE randomMaker(v1 int)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pplGrp
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pplGrp(FirstName_tmp varchar(255), LastName_tmp varchar(255));
  WHILE (v1 > 0) DO
  CALL FirstName_gen();
  CALL LastName_gen();
  INSERT INTO pplGrp (FirstName_tmp, LastName_tmp)values(FirstName_gen(), LastName_gen());
  SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
  select FirstName_tmp as 'First Name', LastName_tmp as 'Last Name' FROM pplGrp
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE randomMaker(v1 int)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pplGrp;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pplGrp(FirstName_tmp varchar(255), LastName_tmp varchar(255));
  WHILE (v1 > 0) DO
    CALL FirstName_gen();
    CALL LastName_gen();
    INSERT INTO pplGrp (FirstName_tmp, LastName_tmp)values(FirstName_gen(), LastName_gen());
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
  select FirstName_tmp as 'First Name', LastName_tmp as 'Last Name' FROM pplGrp;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```